# Is it possible to set Sphinx autodoc module path from Jupyter Book?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, jupyterbook

Is it possible to set the Sphinx `autodoc` Python module path **from Jupyter Book**, for example via `_config.yml`?

I'm using Jupyter Book to document a Python system and publish to Read The Docs. I can set the module path from Sphinx by adding code like this to `conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("my/module/path"))
```

However, I'd prefer to control the path entirely from the Jupyter Book side. Otherwise I have to manually edit `conf.py` after generating the file with `jupyter-book config sphinx path/to/book`.

Comment: A more robust solution would be to avoid mangling the path entirely and using metadata files (`pyproject.toml` or its older brother, `setup.py`) to make the library code installable.

Comment: How do I make the library code installable via `setup.py`?

Comment: There are various guides out there, I'd recommend skipping `setup.py` entirely and use flit with `pyproject.toml` instead https://flit.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Edit suggestion : add the link to the documentation of the API doc integration in Jupyter-Notebook : https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/advanced/developers.html This might be helpful since the official documentations are usually less reachable than question on SO via googling.